# How to dynamically build object with nest objects and arrays

Tags: javascript

I want to dynamically build this object with the data below.

```
var object1 = {
  machines: [
    { 
      node: "01", 
      ram: "8", 
      disks: [ {sdasize: '20'}, {sdbsize: '200'} ],
      mounts: [ {mount: "/var/lib", size: "10"} , {mount: "/home", size: "140"}]
    }, 
    { 
      node: "02", 
      ram: "8",
      disks: [ {sdasize: '75'}, {sdbsize: '300'} ],
      mounts: [ {mount: "/var/log", size: "20"} , {mount: "/var/www/html", size: "200"}]
    }
  ]
};
```

I want to be able to add new machines and make changes to any value or add more mounts to the array that is nested. I have been looking at this for some time with no solution as of yet.

Comment: [Working with objects - JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects)

Comment: Declare the object like: `ver object1 = { machines: [] }`. Add a machine like: `object1.machines.push(machineObject);`. Access a particular machine object like: `object1.machines[ indexOfMachineObject ]`.

Comment: thanks that worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this:

```
var object1 = {machines: []}
function addMachines(node,ram,disks,mounts){
   object1.machines.push({node:node,ram:ram,disks:disks,mounts:mounts})
}
```

Since machines is a `array` we can use `push()` to insert objects inside that `array`.

Now you can use `addMachines` function in a loop or based on `eventlisteners`, and build the `object1` via parameters in that function

Edit:

As commented `below` you can also add a function to build your other objects, like disks and mount.

```
buildDisk(sdasize,sdbsize)
{
    return [{sdasize:sdasize},{sdbsize:sdbsize}]
}
```

Usage:

```
addMachines('01','8',buildDisk(20,50),'nice')
```

what object1 would look like

```
machines:[
    {
        node:'01',
        ram:'8',
        disks:[
            {
                sdasize:20,
                sdbsize:50
            },
        mounts:'nice'
    }];
```

Comment: so node, ram, disks, and mounts would be there own objects since they have nested objects? 

example:
var mounts = { [ {mount: "/var/log", size: "20"} , {mount: "/var/www/html", size: "200"}]};

Comment: thats the idea, when passing parameters to the function of disks and mounts they should have their own object, but you can make a function to build that for you aswell, the same way i did with the machines

Comment: @BStark i added a example of the function of adding disks, should apply the same way with mounts aswell.

Comment: Thanks but is there a way change the value to sdasize on lets say node 02 after its in the object use case I want to override it later.

Comment: yes but you probably will need some kind of identifier of the object, a simple id, so you can search for it later.
if you access the object machines[0].disks[0].sdasize = 0
you'll be setting the sdasize to 0